# Replace part of multiline string with trailing space

Tags: javascript, replace

I have a multiline string with spaces at the end of each line:

```js
console.log(`*Env:* 
*Brand:* `.replace("*Env:* ", "bla"));
```

returns just the original string

How can I replace substring with trailing space?

Comment: Added a working snippet with the original code. Not sure why it wasn't working for you.

Comment: Thanks. I've found the cause - it was no-break space, that's why I cannot find it

Answer (score 1):

if you want to search if there are multiple spaces in the string then you need to use regex.

```js
const regex = / *\*Env\* */

// this regex will search for *Env* in any line with trailing spaces either in left or right

console.log(`       *Env:*         
*Brand:* `.replace(regex, "bla"));
```